# Magento custom option issue?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Is it possible to create 200 sub option of color option in magento 1.9x.

For example : color (type select box)

Sub options are: RED, YELLOW, FLORENCE WALNUT, BOARDWALK OAK , GREEN...up to 200..

I am using magento 1.9x and have create 200 sub options through admin panel.
But in front-end, it only show 109 sub-options.

When i checked the product from back-end `(catalog->manage product -> & go to custom option of product & it is showing only 109 options though i did create 200 options.)`

Comment: " but in front-end, it only show 109 sub-options " where ?

Comment: in product page in which i have create custom option through backend magento admin

Comment: hmm i got it what is your issue.check phpinfo() and search values for `max_input_vars` and `post_max_size` when you want to post too much this value should be higher

Comment: check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) for detail

Comment: yes , i have edit the file & change max_input_vars (from 1000 to 5000) & post_max_size from 50 m to 100 m.

Comment: but when i go to http://localhost/info.php, it is show 1000 & 50 m , though i have changed the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58371/discussion-between-pankaj-and-minesh-patel).

Comment: after edit you need to restart apache